# WPF Grow animation

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

I am looking for a nice way to display some help messages in my application and I was looking to have the user click a button. This would then trigger a area at the top to grow and show the help section. The only problem is i am not sure how to acomplish this.

Any help is appreciated as I am new to wpf.

Comment: take a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142770/grow-shrink-wpf-animation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at this MSDN tutorial on how to use WPF Storyboards:
[Storyboards Overview (.NET Framework 4.0)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742868(v=vs.100).aspx)

I think one of the examples there is actually what you need.